# Netbeans 7.1.2 C/C++ MinGW build errors

Tags: netbeans, mingw

I have installed Netbeans and MinGW to use as a C/C++ IDE but am failing to compile the provided samples in Netbeans. I'm getting the following build errors:

```
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o.d
gcc.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o main.c
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Momo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Test2'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Momo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Test2'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 4s)
```

Comment: Are you using Cygwin `make`, MinGW MSYS `make`, or MinGW `make`? MinGW `make` is [unsupported](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html#mingw). Install MinGW MSYS `make`.